# Do while loop C coding error

Tags: c

What is going wrong here? I am getting the error `Use of undeclared identifier 'answer'`

Here's my code:

```
        if (CalculatorChoice == 1) do {
            int a;
            int b;
            int sum;
            char answer;

            printf ("You have choosen addition, please enter first number: ");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            printf ("Now please enter second number to addit: ");
            scanf("%d", &b);
            printf("The sum is: %d \n\n", sum = a+b);

            printf("Do you want to go back to menupage? (y/n): ");
            answer = getchar();
            getchar();
        } while(answer=='y');
```

Comment: `char answer;` must be defined before do-while. and  `answer = getchar(); getchar();` --> `getchar(); answer = getchar();`

Comment: The problem is from "while(answer=='y');" :-(

Comment: Also , `answer=='y'` --> `answer != 'y'` or `answer == 'n'` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (CalculatorChoice == 1)
  do {
    /* ... */
    char answer;

    /* ... */
  } while(answer=='y');
```

You have declared the variable `answer` *inside* the loop block, but it is accessed from the `while` condition, which is *outside* the loop block.

You can move the declaration outside the loop body to fix this:

```
if (CalculatorChoice == 1) {
  char answer;
  do {
    /* ... */
  } while(answer=='y');
}
```

Comment: This neither fixed the problem. "while(answer=='y');"

Comment: Did you put brackets around the `if` body, as in my answer?

Comment: @FrederikHansen BLUEPIXY is correct, in that your character consumption is wrong. You're retaining the next char after your second number input (which is likely a newline), then throwing out the following character (which is likely your `y` or `n`. Look at the first comment below your question. You need to throw out the newline, and retain the next char, not retain the newline and throw out the next char. (and honestly, a more robust way of consuming through a newline is likely in order). *Then*, move `answer` outside the loop as shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Your version has variable declared inside block, is not accessible out of block

This code changes position

```
if (CalculatorChoice == 1) 
{
  char answer;

  do {
    int a;
    int b;
    int sum;

    printf ("You have choosen addition, please enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf ("Now please enter second number to addit: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("The sum is: %d \n\n", sum = a+b);

    printf("Do you want to go back to menupage? (y/n): ");
    answer = getchar();
    getchar();
    } while(answer=='y');
  }
```

Comment: Please don't just post code, but explain the solution and how it differs from the code already in the question.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem.